# jquery datepicker missing (wordpress) after updating to 5.26 from 4.6.33?

Tags: wordpress, jquery, date-range

A site I inherited a while back finally needed to be updated to a much more modern level including PHP version, MariaDB version and Wordpress version along with CiviCRM.
Seen first in the LYBNTY report - the date range fields are simply dropdowns with entries like 'Yesterday', 'Last week', etc. but no ability to actually pick a date range.
I have checked Access Control which all looks good (but I am administrator so should have all those already).
Checked the header links for jquery and seems I have access to them.
Is there a setting somewhere to turn jquery entities off/on?  Or could I be missing a path even though the update was in place and not moved?
Everything else seems to be working just fine.
I might add that the Summary Fields extension is still quite old and is marked as needed an update.  Could this have anything to do with this as in not being compatible with the 5.26 version of CiviCRM?
I'm stumped here so any suggestions would be fantastic!
TIA!

Comment: In checking more, I am getting a console error of:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Freport%2Finstance%2F10&reset=1&output=criteria:774)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)`
Which is called in calling the datepicker.  Could I just have an old version of jquery that needs to be replaced?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind - all working now.
I modified the CiviCRM Resource URL from the default that was in there of [civicrm.root]
to be the full URL http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm and the choice of 'Choose Date Range' showed up in the drop down giving the functionality needed.
Or it is entirely possible that Choose Date Range was there the whole time and I just missed it.  Been such a slog of updating this ancient site that that is entirely possible.
Strangely, that jquery error is still showing up in the console, though.  But I will look at that tomorrow.